# Custom Taxonomy Doesn't Show Up

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Have a snippet here that doesn't seem to show up the taxonomy in the CPT edit screen. Not sure what's wrong, both the taxonomy and CPT are registered to each other.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'create_taxonomy');

function create_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( 'farm', array('farmer', 'food', 'recipe'), array(
        'label'                                 => 'farms',
        'public'                                => true,
        'show_ui'                               => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'                     => true,
        'show_tagcloud'                     => true,
        'hierarchical'                          => true,
        'show_admin_column'                     => true,
        'query_var'                         => 'farm',
        'update_count_callback' => '',
        'sort'                                  => true,
        'labels'                                => array(
            'name'                                              => __('Farms'),
            'singular_name'             => __('Farm'),
            'menu_name'                                     => __('Farm'),
            'all_items'                                     => __('All Farms'),
            'edit_item'                                     => __('Edit Farm'),
            'view_item'                                     => __('View Farm'),
            'update_item'                                   => __('Update Farm'),
            'add_new_item'                              => __('Add New Farm'),
            'new_item_name'                             => __('New Farm'),
            'search_items'                              => __('Search Farms'),
            'popular_items'                             => __('Popular Farms'),
            'separate_items_with_commas'    => __('Separate farms by commas'),
            'add_or_remove_items'                   => __('Add or remove farms'),
            'choose_from_most_used'             => __('Choose from the most popular farms'),
            'not_found'                                     => __('No farms found')
        ),
        'rewrite'                               => array(
            'slug'                  => 'farm',
            'with_front'        => false,
            'hierarchical'  => false,
        )
    ) );

    register_post_type( 'farmer', array(
        'public'                    => true,
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'farm' ),
        'menu_position'     => 6,
        'capability_type'   => 'page',
        'rewrite'                   => array( 'slug' => 'farmer' ),
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'labels'                    => array(
        'name'                              => __('Farmers'),
        'menu_name'                     => __('Farmers'),
        'singular_name'             => __('Farmer'),
        'add_new'                           => __('Add New'),
        'add_new_item'              => __('Add New Farmer'),
        'edit_item'                     => __('Edit Farmer'),
        'new_item'                      => __('New Farmer'),
        'all_items'                     => __('All Farmers'),
        'view_item'                     => __('View Farmer'),
        'search_items'              => __('Search Farmers'),
        'not_found'                     => __('No farmers found'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No farmers found in Trash')
        )
    ) );}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code WordPress 3.5.1 installation, and it works just fine.

Check the WordPress version you are using and the changelog to find out if something that can interfere with your CPT and taxonomy is different in your version than in 3.5.1

Comment: I am using 3.5.1 as well.

Comment: Try flushing the permalinks or use the recommended http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type after both custom post type and taxonomy have been registered

Comment: Done...not sure what's wrong, but I rewrote the code and it seems to be working...Guess WP is having a bad day once in a while...